# How to change / add values of same items in openpyxl in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

The data I had [Without modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSFx8.png).

Code:

```
for row in range(2, 6):
    result_cell = 'A{}'.format(row)
    column_a = ws[row("Quantity") + int(row)].value
    column_b = ws[row["Fruit"] +str(row)].value

    ws[result_cell] =  column_a + column_b
```

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD6vN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, you wanted the sum of values with the same key. For this purpose you can use a dictionary, in which you store the row number of the first time that the key appeared. For instance, in your example the dictionary would be something like: `{"Apple": 2, "Banana": 3, "Orange":5}`. Using this idea the code would be something like this:

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("<path_to_your_file>")
sheet = workbook['<sheet_name>']

index_dict = {}
rows_to_delete = []
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value
    if name not in index_dict: # if it's the first time that this key (or name) has been seen
        index_dict[name] = row
    else: # if the key has been seen before
        sheet.cell(row=index_dict[name], column=2).value = (
            sheet.cell(row=index_dict[name], column=2).value
            + sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value
        ) #  the value gets added to the first row with this key
        rows_to_delete.append(row) # add the row number with duplicated key

# delete the duplicated rows
for row in rows_to_delete[::-1]:
    sheet.delete_rows(row)

workbook.save(file_path)
```

Comment: hey dude! I went through your code but results me error regarding that sheet is not defined.

Comment: @Monikbudhv113 You should read the sheet according to your file name and path. I have edited my code, replace `<path_to_file>` with the path to your file and `<sheet_name>` with your sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with one loop in a similar vein like this;
Starting from the bottom and moving the pointers up, adding the value to the next valid row then deleting the old row as the pointer is moved.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

rpointer = {}
### Reverse loop start at max row 
for row in reversed(range(2, ws.max_row+1)): 
    cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=1)
    c_value = cell.value

    if c_value in rpointer:  # Check if fruit already has a pointer
        old_row = rpointer[c_value]  # last row to hold this fruit 

        ### Update fruit row pointers if row deletion will move them up 
        for fruit, rownum in rpointer.items(): 
            rpointer[fruit] = rownum-1 if rownum > old_row else rownum

        ### Add the value in old fruit row to value of new fruit row    
        cell.offset(column=1).value += cell.offset(row=old_row-row, column=1).value

        ### Delete the old fruit row
        ws.delete_rows(old_row)

    ### Set row pointer for a new or current fruit 
    rpointer[c_value] = row

wb.save("foo1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Or just use a default dictionary.